# I have a text file where I need to extract duplicate data from. The problem is I need it in a particular format. How is this done in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, duplicates

I have a tab delimited file that I’m trying to extract duplicates from. This is the example text file:

```
A       B   
-----   -----  
123     1   
123     2    
978     3   
546     2   
789     1   
999     4
789     2
```

I already know how to get the duplicates from column A:

```
$d = Import-Csv “text.txt” delimiter “`t” | Group-Object “A” | Where-Object {$_.count -gt 1}
```

But that’s not all I want. Is it possible to get this format?

```
A       B   
-----   -----  
123     1   
123     2    
789     1   
789     2
```

Comment: after you group the items, there will be a `.Group` property that will hold ALL the matching items. iterate thru that to get each of the objects.

Comment: As @Lee_Dailey suggested or simply append `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in above comments you need to expand the `group` property:

```
 Import-Csv .\test.csv -Delimiter "`t" | group A | ? Count -gt 1 | select  -ExpandProperty group

 A   B
 -   --
 123 1
 123 2
 789 1
 789 2
```

Comment: @scd, please mark the solution as correct one, up vote would also be nice. Thx.